# Get Mapbox Draw shape as CSS

Tags: css, mapbox, mapbox-gl, turfjs

Following [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/):  I've implemented Mapbox's draw as a feature on the map I created.

I want to get the shape the user has drawn and display it as a css (or svg) shape.

```
draw = new MapboxDraw({
  displayControlsDefault: false,
  controls: {
    polygon: true,
    trash: true
  },
  defaultMode: 'draw_polygon'
});

map.addControl(draw);
```

Above code, where map is a mapboxgl map, works fine. The user can draw a polygon shape on the map. Using Turfjs I can get the area, or coordinates drawn by the user. But I'm not sure how to translate this shape to a css or svg shape to use outside of the map. Any ideas?

Comment: mapboxGL will render your shape directly to your canvas. So there's nothing like an svg overlay/layer (like in some leaflet approaches). But you might extract your shape's coordinates by `const coordinates = draw.getAll()` and create an svg polyline from the retrieved coordinates. Certainly a bit tricky since you'll have to assemble your coordinates to a new object/array then you might have to shrink them to reasonable values (lat, lng) ... and eventually create a path/polyline (not too difficult).  An existing mapbox plugin would be preferrable.

Comment: Maybe look at this if you really need SVG? https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-to-svg If you are just trying to display it a second time with a different design, you could just make a second map (a second instance of mapboxGL) with a different style. You could even render it on an empty white background with navigation disabled.